# Setting the value (selected option) of a dijit.form.Select widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a dijit.form.Select widget. It's tied to a data store, if that matters. It's filled with several options already. All I want to do is programmatically set its value. I can get its value using `myWidget.attr('value')` but if I try to do `myWidget.attr('value', 5)` for example (where 5 is one of the valid values), all it does is reset the widget to select the very first option, no matter what value I give it.

This seems to be a bug, and there aren't any tests or documentation which show how to accomplish what I want to. But is there some way, even if it's a dirty hack?

I'm using Dojo 1.4.0. Note that dijit.form.Select is the new name for dojox.form.DropDownSelect.

edit: I even tried resetting the widget with all new options, but it ignores the option which has `selected = true` and just selects the first option. There must still be a way though.

Comment: There is a test page here: http://bit.ly/9qitSk that you can mess with.  Using fire-bug I used dijit.byId('s9').attr('value', 'CO') successfully on that page.  That will set the "store-based" Select on that page.

Comment: @Joe B Awesome thanks - I'd seen that before, but didn't see a value setting example. I had tried doing that in firebug with my own Select widget, which didn't work, so I wonder what's different...

Comment: BTW post that as an answer and I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even if your values are ints, if you set your integer to a string then this will work.

```
dijit.byId( 'my_select' ).attr( 'value', String( 5 ) );
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Please note that from Dojo 2.0 attr() won't work anymore.

Answer (score 11):

Turns out it's a bug - if the option values aren't strings, it won't work (mine were integers).

Comment: It's actually a side effect of how arrays/hashes work in js, I think. if you use an int, it will think you're indexing the array, instead of using it as a hash.

Answer (score 2):

Repost of my comment:
There is a test page here: [dojo archive](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_Select.html) that you can mess with. Using fire-bug I used dijit.byId('s9').attr('value', 'CO') successfully on that page. That will set the "store-based" Select on that page.

But as you said I set it using a string and you were using integers so I didn't see the bug.  Good catch.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem (but trying to click on an item in the dropdown). Here I'm using Dojo 1.7.3 and most definitely using Stringrs! :/